# How to verify WIFI wake lock using adb command

Tags: android, android-wifi, wakelock, android-wake-lock

Can someone tell me is there any adb command to verify wifi wake lock in android phone. I am trying to check that wake lock is active or not after acquire from my application but not found this information in following file:

```
 adb shell "cat /sys/kernel/debug/wakeup_sources"
```

Is it written somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

To list the wifilocks active in android device, use the following command.

adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep "your wake_lock tag name"

Example:

adb shell dumpsys wifi | grep wake_lock_next

output:

WifiLock{wake_lock_next type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@420bcfd0}